# Polymer Unexpected Method Scope on Callback

Tags: javascript, html, module, scope, polymer

## Background

I'm working with Polymer .5 as an html web component layer, on top of that I've built a modular JS Core, for pub-sub eventing, based on designs by Nicholas Zakas and a [walkthrough](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-modular-javascript--net-14746) by Andrew Burgess.

I know that there are other methods for achieving this, outlined in the Polymer [Communications and Messaging Page](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-modular-javascript--net-14746). But, I don't like core-signals, the recommended pub-sub method, as much as a proper JS Core and Sandbox.

My issue is that when I pass a Method inside of my Polymer definition as a callback for a specific event.  When that an event is raised and the method gets called from the Core, 'this' reflects the list of bound events rather than methods and properties in the Polymer element.  Which means I can't update any of my data-bound variables to effectively update the DOM of my element.

## Code

This Code has been stripped down to show the pertinent methods that reflect the issue

```
<polymer-element name="product-panel"> <template>

<div id="product-panel">
    <content>
    <ul>

        <template repeat="{{item in list}}">
        <li id="{{item.id}}" data-unique-keyword="{{item.keywords}}" style="{{item.styleString}}" on-click="{{addToCart}}"><img src="/ptp/resources/img/{{item.imgFile}}">
            <p>{{item.label}}</p></li>
        </template>
    </ul>
    </content>
</div>

</template> <script>
    Polymer('product-panel', {
    ready : function() {

        this.input = 'test-input';
        this.list = [{id: '1', keywords: 'red', imgFile:'1.jpg', label:'First Item', style:{width:"120px"}, styleString:''},
                     {id: '2', keywords: 'blue', imgFile:'2.jpg', label:'Second Item', style:{}, styleString:''},
                     {id: '3', keywords: 'mobile', imgFile:'3.jpg', label:'Third Item', style:{}, styleString:''}];

        this.name = 'panel';
        this.sandbox = null;

        CORE.create_module(this.name, function(sb, lns) {
        if(lns){
            lns.sandbox = sb;
        }       

        return {
            init : function() {
            },
            destroy : function() {
            }};
        }, this);

        this.sandbox.listen({'perform-search' : this.searchPlain});
        CORE.start(this.name, this);
    },
    searchPlain : function(query) {
        for (; product = this.list[i++];) {
        if (product.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
            product.style.opacity = '0.2';
        }
        }

        }
    });
    </script> </polymer-element>
    </html>
```

The notable portions are the sandbox.listen method which binds the searchPlain method to the perform-search event.  I can confirm this method is getting called back correctly, but it does not have access to the data-bound this.list so it's unable to update the values.

If I inspect 'this' through Dev Tools in Chrome 42, I see it has access to the list of bound events and their methods.  This leads me to believe this is accessing the scope of the Core from where the callback is being made.

## Question

Is it expected that passing a Polymer method as a callback like this will cause it to lose its local scope?

if so is there another way to bind these methods to events with a JS Core, or a workaround to be able to access the local element variables from a callback method?

Comment: https://github.com/youssef06/polymer-login-form/blob/master/login-form/js/login-form.js  polymer is diff.   i dont know if it will help 2 understand the genl issue of  reference to locals but check the "Ready()" in the link @61 and whats done at the top to preserve refs to local state... I found this code odd  but IMO it may be addressing similar issues??

Comment: @RobertRowntree that's a good point, I got it to access the local property, after significant restructuring.  To get it working I have to include all of my method definitions inside of the ready function, and if you look at the CORE.create_module method I pass 'this' as a parameter at the end, and the lns param you see in the function is that local state 'this' being passed back that's how I'm able to save an instance of sandbox for each element.  i can then access lns.list in my callback methods, but this seems like a hack, and also my methods aren't exposed so they can't be reused.

Comment: based on how core-signal works in there examples; I thought there might be a more natural way to declare a method that can be used/bound in the html and also passed as a stateful callback for a custom event.  though there may be a lot of infrastructure to make that work in core-signal?